# Selenium IDE target of subsequent cell in table based on first cells content

Tags: selenium-ide

Basically, in English I want to tell Selenium "look for the content ttc202 in column one, of a multi-row, multicolumn table, then mouseOver on the Edit link"

HTML is as follows:

```
 <tr id="86" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr ui-state-highlight" tabindex="0" role="row" aria-selected="true">
<td aria-describedby="jqLst_Short Name" style="text-align:left;" role="gridcell">
    ttc202
</td>
<td aria-describedby="jqLst_Long Name" style="text-align:left;" role="gridcell">
    Testing Training Company 202
</td>
<td aria-describedby="jqLst_Actions" title="" style="text-align:center;" role="gridcell">
    <a class="act avw" title="View this Organisation" href="company/view?lcId=86"></a>
    <a class="act aed" title="Edit this Organisation" href="company/edit?lcId=86"></a>
</td>
</tr>
```

I have tried this:

```
//td[contains(text(),'ttc202')]/following-sibling::td[contains(a/title(),'Edit this Organisation')]/a
```

All help appreciated. I assume I am missing something to skip over the first column, but can't imagine what will enable me to do that...

Progress:

I have found the following as an alternative which should get to the correct cell, but I am not able to workout how to target the title in the link code:

```
//td[normalize-space() ="ttc202"])[1]/following-sibling::td[2]/a[. = 'Edit']
```

I think this is progress just not sufficient to get me to the finish line!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much investigation I found the following answer, perhaps this might help others who come across this question:

```
//tr[contains(td[1], "ttc202")]/td[3]/a[@title='Edit this Organisation']
```

The trick was realising which cell the information was in (represented by the square brackets).